# Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Here’s the model in question:

```
batch_size = 1
epochs = 1

…

input_size = 9
output_size = 1
hidden_size_1 = 9

input_layer = tf.keras.Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, input_size))
input_layer_expanded = tf.expand_dims(input_layer, axis=-1)
hidden_1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size_1, stateful=True)(input_layer_expanded)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(hidden_1)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(input_data, output_data, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
model.save("model_1.h5")
```

The input is giving 9 values at once, and the output is a single value.

But when in another script I run this code:

```
model_path = "model_1.h5"
model = models.load_model(model_path)
file = "test_data.csv"

…

for index, row in data.drop(columns=['Close_next']).iterrows(): 
    output = model.predict(row.values, batch_size=1)
```

I get this error:
`Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 1)`
even though the data format is the same

The shape outputted by the input layer seems to change when I do “predict” compared to “fit”.

Comment: what's the output of `print(row.values)` in the first iteration fo the loop before the predict call?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia : it's just a tensor of the 9 input values, as should be. The issue arises somehow when passing it to the lstm layer

Comment: @agheieff, The input of the LSTM is always is a 3D array (batch_size, time_steps, seq_len). Please pass the data to the model in the mentioned format while training. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The input of the Lstm is should be a 3D array.

If you pass the 2d array

```
input_data = tf.constant([[1]])

lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=64)

output = lstm_layer(input_data)
```

you will get the error ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 1)

If you pass the 3d array to input like input_data = tf.constant([[[1.]]]),it works fine. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/kiransair/51728ce4f758eb92f2e983dff0b8caba/so_74818458.ipynb) for working code example. Thank You.